# Windows 10 Task Manager shows two different cpu speeds

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Hi i am trying to understand why my Task Manager shows two different CPU speeds: 3.18 Ghzand 2.21 Ghz. Is there maybe something wrong in my configuration? This is a Surface Pro 4 I7

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Two cores, each currently at a different speed?

Comment: @Xen2050 It's not the different cores, windows only shows one speed for the cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Intel CPUs dynamically change clockspeed both for energy saving and to boost cores depending on load.

A lot of programs are single threaded so it can either boost all four cores a little bit or a single core a lot to fill it's temperature headroom.

Windows doesn't show the individual core speeds.(If you right click on the graph you can 'change graph to' 'logical processors' to see the cores) The two speeds you see are the standard base speed in the name so for an i7-6650U is 2.21GHz and the other speed is what it is currently running at up to 3.4Ghz for this chip. If you close your apps then you'll see it go lower.

Comment: Not just the latest Intel CPU's, it's been on Intels and AMD's since 2003, maybe even 2000. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling

Comment: @Xen2050 you are right but the Microsoft Surface uses an Intel CPU